# Coloured salts for silica garden

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I recently thought about making a silica garden. I have copper sulphate and nickel sulphate right now. What other salts would be the best to put along with these two? Also should I buy sodium silicate directly or should I use silica gel and sodium hydroxide? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest Cobalt Nitrate (reddish-brown) , Iron(III) Chloride (orange) and Zinc Sulphate or Calcium Chloride (both white) as they look good with blue and green (Copper Sulphate and Nickel Sulphate respectively).

If you’re doing this at home and don’t have lab like apparatus, I would suggest buying Sodium Silicate as you are required to heat Sodium Hydroxide in the making of Sodium Silicate, which can be dangerous if proper care is not taken.